# How can we set a div in the counter.razor page of a Blazor app that occupies only the viewport

Tags: blazor, bootstrap-5

In a blazor app that uses bootstrap 5  and in the counter.razor page I would like to embrace the following code:

```
<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>
```

in a   which will have a height equal to the visible part of the page in the browser taking into account the height of the banner at the top of the page where the "About" button appears. I wonder what bootstrap class to use in order to achieve this.

Thank you.

Comment: You should include in your question what you have tried so far that doesn't work. It's also very helpful to include a minimun preproducible example. For blazor you can use [Telerik REPL](https://blazorrepl.telerik.com/) to share your code in the browser.

Comment: In `Counter.razor` you already are in the children part, you could probably do this with some workaround in css or javascript. However, the cleanest way would probably be to modify `MainLayout.razor` or create/use another layout for your page.

Answer (score 0):

Add these two `<article />` styles to the existing media queries in MainLayout.razor.css

```css
@media (max-width: 640.98px) {
...
    article {
        min-height: calc(100vh - 3.5rem);
    }
}

@media (min-width: 641px) {
...
    article {
        height: calc(100% - 3.5rem);
    }

}
```

Note the more recent blazor templates are using `<article />` not `<div />` to contain the page